# How to add axis labels to a multiplot in R?

Tags: r, plot, igraph

I managed to create a single plot with 4 different diagrams. However the axis labels don't show up. As I am a beginner in R I'd appreciate if someone could show me how to add axis labels to this kind of plot.
X-Axis: Degree
Y-Axis: Log(cumulative distribution)

The graph uses igraph-Functions.

Here is the graph:
[image]
And here is my code:

```
par(mar = rep(2, 4))  
par(mfrow=c(2,2))               
ddU <- degree.distribution(USAN_g_num, cumulative=TRUE, mode="in")
plot(ddU,  log="xy", col=ifelse(degree.distribution(USAN_g_num, cumulative=FALSE,     mode="in")==0 ,'white',"black"), 
 pch=ifelse(degree.distribution(USAN_g_num, cumulative=FALSE, mode="in")==0 ,10,20),
 cex=ifelse(degree.distribution(USAN_g_num, cumulative=FALSE, mode="in")==0 ,0,1),xlab="degree", ylab="log(cumulative frequency)",main="USAN") 

  ddS <- degree.distribution(SAg, cumulative=TRUE, mode="in")
  plot(ddS,  log="xy", col=ifelse(degree.distribution(SAg, cumulative=FALSE, mode="in")==0 ,'white',"black"),   
     pch=ifelse(degree.distribution(SAg, cumulative=FALSE, mode="in")==0 ,10,20),
     cex=ifelse(degree.distribution(SAg, cumulative=FALSE, mode="in")==0 ,0,1),xlab="degree", ylab="log(cumulative frequency)",main="SA") 

  ddO <- degree.distribution(OWg, cumulative=TRUE, mode="in")
  plot(ddO,  log="xy", col=ifelse(degree.distribution(OWg, cumulative=FALSE, mode="in")==0 ,'white',"black"),  
    pch=ifelse(degree.distribution(OWg, cumulative=FALSE, mode="in")==0 ,10,20),
    cex=ifelse(degree.distribution(OWg, cumulative=FALSE, mode="in")==0 ,0,1),xlab="degree", ylab="log(cumulative frequency)",main="OW") 

  ddT <- degree.distribution(STg, cumulative=TRUE, mode="in")
  plot(ddT,  log="xy", col=ifelse(degree.distribution(OWg, cumulative=FALSE, mode="in")==0 ,'black',"black"),  
    pch=ifelse(degree.distribution(STg, cumulative=FALSE, mode="in")==0 ,10,20),
    cex=ifelse(degree.distribution(STg, cumulative=FALSE, mode="in")==0 ,0,1),xlab="degree", ylab="log(cumulative frequency)",main="ST")
```

Thank you

Comment: What package/library does degree.distribution function belong?

Comment: @AndreSilva It belongs to igraph

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't see the x and y axis labels because you set too narrow margin for the bottom and left side of plots with `mar=`. Try to increase it to 4 or higher.

```
par(mar = c(4,4,2,2))  
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
plot(1:10,xlab="mm",ylab="kk")
plot(1:10,xlab="mm",ylab="kk")
plot(1:10,xlab="mm",ylab="kk")
plot(1:10,xlab="mm",ylab="kk")
```